# i want to know how to use android soft keyboard's enter button to search in edit TextView instead clicking search button

Tags: java, android, html, android-studio

I want to know how to use Android soft keyboard's enter button to search in edit TextView instead of clicking the search button.

In my app when I click the enter button of the soft keyboard after writing a web address it goes to the next line instead of searching for the web address but it works fine when I click on the search button.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a `KeyListener` for the UI element handling user input that will receive entered keys, and if someone hit enter, then emulate the click in searchButton or run the searching code.

Comment: I don't know how to write codes for KeyListner... can you plz give me a demo